# OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException : Modal dialog present error message

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I'm attaching the code along with the screenshot from the application. I've got this prompt window in which a text needs to be entered. The Page objects contains all the required information about the page but the scripts fails as it doesn't recognize the prompt window.

[image]

```
using System;
using CSharpAutomationFramework.Framework.Base;
using CSharpAutomationFramework.Framework.Core;
using CSharpAutomationFramework.Framework.Helpers;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace CSharpTestAutomation.PageObjects.Tcfa
{
    public class CashLoadingHo : BasePage
    {
        readonly String txtCarrierId = "id:=txtCLcarrierId";
        readonly String txtEnterCarrierId = "id:=txtCLcarrierId";
        readonly String btnCheckCarrierId = "id:=CmdCheckCarrierID";
        readonly String lstCashLoadType = "id:=ddlCLcashLoadType";
        readonly String lstCustomerAccountNumber = "id:=ddlCLcustAcId";
        readonly String lstPayment = "id:=ddlCLpayID";
        readonly String txtMerchantId = "id:=txtCLmerchantId";
        readonly String btnCheckMerchantId = "id:=CmdMerchantID";
        readonly String txtAmount = "id:=txtCLamt";
        readonly String txtEnterAmount = "id:=txtCLamt";
        readonly String txtNameofDepositor = "id:=txtCLdepositor";
        readonly String btnSave = "id:=CmdSave";
        readonly String btnPrintReceipt = "id:=cmdCLreceiptPrint";

        public CashLoadingHo(IWebDriver driver, Reporting reporter) : base(driver, reporter)
        {
            wrapper.SwitchToDefaultContent()
                   .SwitchToFrameWithName("main");
        }
        public CashLoadingHo CarrieridCheck(String carrierid)
        {
            wrapper.EnterText(txtCarrierId, carrierid)
                   .Click(btnCheckCarrierId);

            return this;

        }

        public CashLoadingHo CashLoadingDetails(String merchantid, String cashloadtype, String customeraccountnumber, String payment, string amount, string nameofthedepositor)

        {
            wrapper.SelectOptionFromList(lstCashLoadType, cashloadtype)
                   .SelectOptionFromList(lstCustomerAccountNumber, customeraccountnumber)
                   .SelectOptionFromList(lstPayment, payment)
                   .EnterText(txtMerchantId, merchantid)
                   .Click(btnCheckMerchantId)
                   .EnterText(txtAmount, amount)
                   .EnterText(txtNameofDepositor, nameofthedepositor);
            return this;
        }

        public CashLoadingHo ClickSave()
        {
            wrapper.Click(btnSave)
                   .AcceptAlert();
            return this;
        }

        public CashLoadingHo EnterCarrierId(string entercarrierid)
        {
            wrapper.EnterText(txtEnterCarrierId, entercarrierid);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Result Message:OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException : Modal dialog present

I am getting the above error message on running the script. i have also attached the screenshot of the prompt window that appears after saving the given data in the application.

Comment: Than please [edit] your question with the additional information.

Comment: I have edited the question. The Code given is the complete page objects of the screenshot. you can see a prompt window at the top in the screenshot. After providing all the mandatory information and clicking on SAVE button. The prompt window appears for entering additional information to confirm it. My code works fine till you enter the mandatory information and clicking on save button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple, First switch to the Prompt Alert `driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` and Then pass the value/text using `.sendKey()` and finally, accept the Prompt Alert using `.Accept()`

Please try below code

```
//This step produce an alert on screen
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/p[11]/button"));

// 'IJavaScriptExecutor' is an 'interface' which is used to run the 'JavaScript code' into the webdriver (Browser)        
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);

// Switch the control of 'driver' to the Alert from main window
IAlert promptAlert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();

// Get the Text of Alert
String alertText = promptAlert.Text;
Console.WriteLine("Alert text is " + alertText);

//'.SendKeys()' to enter the text in to the textbox of alert 
promptAlert.SendKeys("Accepting the alert");
Thread.Sleep(4000); //This sleep is not necessary, just for demonstration

// '.Accept()' is used to accept the alert '(click on the Ok button)'
promptAlert.Accept();
```

Credit: [ToolsQA](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/how-to-handle-different-types-of-alert-and-popup-box-in-selenium-csharp/)

Comment: Thanks Bhavin. Your Solution was easily understandable. It too worked perfectly fine in my code. Can i contact you directly. i have few more clarifications regarding the framework which i use.

Comment: @Hargovind, If my solution is work for you then Accept my answer first. You can refer how can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Swap to your alert with `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys(/* The text to send to the alert textbox*/);`

And then just accept it with `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();`

Or you can close it from the beginning `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();`

You can modify your save function to enter your Carrier ID, but I would advice against it, since you would have to enter a Carrier ID even though you just want to "save". Maybe at some point, you can click save and the alert won't appear.

```
public CashLoadingHo ClickSave()
{
    wrapper.Click(btnSave)
           .AcceptAlert();
    return this;
}

public CashLoadingHo AlertEnterCarrierId(string id)
{
    WaitForAlert(); //Explained below
    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys(id);
    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
    //Now, swap back to your main window.
    driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    return this;
}

public CashLoadingHo AlertEnterAmount(string amount)
{
    WaitForAlert(); //Explained below
    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys(amount);
    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
    //Now, swap back to your main window.
    driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    return this;
}
```

Then, just call the 3 functions one after the other. But, from my experience, you should wait for the alert to appear so you don't get exceptions for the alert not being present. Create a wait function that the other 2 (the two functions that handle the alert) will call.

```
public CashLoadingHo WaitForAlert()
{
    //Initialize your wait object.
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Really thanks for your solution.Basically i am a beginner in c# scripting. can you please help me where exactly i need to do the changes within the code. If you see the screenshot once i have entered all the mandatory information and click on "SAVE" the prompt window comes where i want to enter the Carried id and click on "OK" after clicking on "OK" another prompt window appears where in i need to enter the amount and again click on "OK". my script runs perfectly fine only till clicking the "SAVE" button. Please Help me with this.

Comment: Really Thanks  a lot. This Solution worked absolutely perfect.

Comment: Your Answer is Accepted Sir